# React / Bootstrap Grid System: Responsive Cols not working as expected but overflowing

Tags: css, grid, react-bootstrap

I am using the *Bootstrap Grid System* in order to make this list (3 columns) responsive. I am also using this with react.
The goal is that on large screens, I can fit all 3 columns in one row. On medium screens I fit two columns in one row and the last one in the last row. On very small screens I fit each column in one row.

It is working, however it is not pushing the columns on each row, its rather overflowing.
**What am I missing?**

```
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div className="col-tab">
                                <h4>Heading 1</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>test1</li>
                                    <li>test2</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div className="col-tab">
                                <h4>Heading 2</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>test 3</li>
                                    <li>test 4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div className="col-tab">
                                <h4>Heading 3</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Test4</li>
                                    <li>TEst 5</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: does Bootstrap work anywhere else in the project ? ?

Comment: Yes, it works everywhere else

Comment: Ok I don't see any problem. I suggest you inspect the columns in the browser and check  if the class style rules is applied to the columns or not